# Run ant deploy script on eclipse save

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have an ant deploy script I would like to run each time I do a file save in eclipse.

Thanks

Vickus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you have to set up eclipse so it builds your project when you save. You do this under "Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Build Automatically".
Second, you have to register your ant builder. Do this via Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New. Here you can select an ant builder and configure it to your preferences.